# How do I get my python virtual assistant to only listen once it hears a wake word?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I have a python virtual assistant that is always listening for commands. How can I make it so she only starts listening to commands once she hears the wake word such as Alexa, or in this case Anna. If you have any tips or answers they will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

tts = pyttsx3.init()

voices = tts.getProperty('voices')
tts.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def takeCommand():

    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Listening...')

        r.pause_threshold = 0.5
        audio = r.listen(source)
        
        try:
            print("Recognizing")
            
            Query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
            print("the command is printed=", Query)
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("Say that again")
            return "None"
        
        return Query

def Take_query():

    while(True):

        query = takeCommand().lower()
        if "Hello" in query:
            tts.say('Hello')
            tts.runAndWait()
            continue

        elif "How are you" in query:
            tts.say('I am good')
            tts.runAndWait()
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Take_query()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Anna` will always listen, so you have 2 choices

1. force the program to ignore any query without `Anna`

so the program will ignore anything doesn't start with `Anna`

```
def takeCommand():

    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Listening...')

        r.pause_threshold = 0.5
        audio = r.listen(source)
        
        try:
            print("Recognizing")
            
            Query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
            print("the command is printed=", Query)
            
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("Say that again")
            return "None"
        if Query.startswith("Anna"):
            return Query
        else:
            return "None"
```

2. Nested recognition

this is might be better for you, just nest the recognition, first recognize `Anna` then and only then the command

hope that helps you

Comment: So what your saying is that if Anna is the first word in the query she will be activated, but If I say "hey anna" she won't be activated?

Comment: you can add possible phrases, or just `if "anna" in Query`

Comment: Also, I used the code you gave me but I'm getting an error at the `if Query.startswith("Anna"`. Here is the error: `Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

Comment: I was able to fix the bug. Thank you! it works perfectly!